# Easy Way To Close Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

This question might sound simple but I can't find the answer i'm looking for.
I have a Login_Form and a Main_Form.
Once I log into the Main_Form I just make it visible and I activate it because I don't want my Login_Form to close.
My question is, is there a way to close both forms at the same time from the Main_Form?
The `this.Close();` will only close the current form.

```
if (access)
{
    Main_Form mainForm = new Main_Form();
    mainForm.Visible = true;
    mainForm.Activate();
}
```

This is where I Instantiate the main_form how can I pass a reference to the login_form?
Thanks in advance and remember the Login_Form must remain open until I close it from the Main_Form!

*Feedback*

After looking at which of your answers I would use I found out about the `Application.Close()` Method Which closes all the forms. Should have taught about this before posting here thanks everyone.

Comment: Is the Main_Form a member variable of the Login_Form? More details are needed on the design of your object graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Main form has a reference to the Login form you can call the close method on it. How you do that is up to you.

- You could pass the reference in to the Main from FROM the login form when you show it.
- You could keep a global reference to the Login Form. (think [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern))
- any other way you can think of

For example:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    Form loginform;
    public MainForm(Form loginForm)
    {
        this.loginForm = loginForm;
    }

    public void CloseForms()
    {
        loginForm.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

In your Active() method, just pass the login form in. Alternatively you can use the code above, and just pass `this` into the constructor instead of the Active() method.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    Form loginform;
    public Active(Form loginForm)
    {
        this.loginForm = loginForm;
    }

    public void CloseForms()
    {
        loginForm.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
}

//from the LOGIN form
if (access)
    {
        Main_Form mainForm = new Main_Form();
        mainForm.Visible = true;
         mainForm.Activate(this); //this is a reference to the current form. LOGIN in this case

     }
```

Comment: I like this approach i'll update my question with some Code line because I can't quite figure out how to pass the reference to the main_form.

Comment: Avoid passing any parameters through constructor of the Form/Control or you'll mess up the Designer. Use properties instead.

Comment: @surfen thanks it has been a long time since I have touched winforms. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the login form then call `Close` on that form.

```
Login_Form.Close()
```

You will have modify the constructor of Main_Form to accept login form instance as a parameter

Comment: I like this approach i'll update my question with some Code line because I can't quite figure out how to pass the reference to the main_form.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [AddOwnedForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.addownedform.aspx#Y0) Method.

From above link:

> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the
>   owner form. For example, consider a form named Form2 that is owned by
>   a form named Form1. If Form1 is closed or minimized, Form2 is also
>   closed or hidden. Owned forms are also never displayed behind their
>   owner form. You can use owned forms for windows such as find and
>   replace windows, which should not be displayed behind the owner form
>   when the owner form is selected.

Code:

```
Form loginForm = new Form();
this.AddOwnedForm(loginForm);
loginForm.Show();
```

Edit:

```
Form mainForm = new Form();
mainForm.Visible = true;
mainForm.AddOwnedForm(this);
mainForm.Activate();
```

now if you close the mainForm it will close both forms.

Comment: oooh Didn't know about that method and it makes it way more simple ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: But mark what if this LoginForm is my default Form called by the program.cs in 

`Application.Run(new Login_Form());`

This Form is Instantiated without a name no?
How could I make a Form AddOwned this form?

Comment: So Login_Form is the parent form and you are creating the mainForm from it then you would use this instead of the form name to assign it to the mainForm. See above edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot I like the Idea And will remember this method.
But as silly as it sounds the only thing I needed is `Application.Close()` 
And I didn't know I could do that..
Since I need to close the whole program this seems to be my best option. What do you think?

Comment: Since your Login_Form is the main program that is being run, you are correct in that `Application.Close()` is easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `Application.Exit();` not `Application.Close();`